# What on earth did I do wrong with texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting

I started trying to paint my model today, but it only paints on a grid-like area of the UV map. It's my first time doing something like this and I couldn't find anywhere that had a similar problem, so I'm lost.[image]

Comment: It looks like you've assigned a checker texture to your brush. Check the *Texture* panel.

Comment: maybe share your file with the images packed within: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/